# Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ORDER'

Tags: sql, asp

Comecei a realizar um programa em asp clássico e numa parte desse programa escrevi o seguinte código:

```
<%

    SQL = " SELECT Id =   TCD.Id "_
        & "   ,     IdTipoContrato  =   TC.IdTipoContrato  "_
        & "   ,     Codigo          =   TCD.Codigo "_
        & "   ,     Mercado         =   M.Mercado "_
        & "   ,     Empresa         =   M.EmpresaBD "_
        & "   ,     Valor           =   TCD.Valor " _
        & "   ,     Descricao       =   TCD.Descricao "_ 
        & "   ,     Moeda           =   MDS.Moeda  "_ 
        & "   ,     Ativo           =  TCD.Ativo "_ 
        & " FROM        LI_TipoContratosDetalhe TCD  WITH (NOLOCK) "_
        & " INNER JOIN  LI_TipoContratos        TC   WITH (NOLOCK) ON TCD.IdTipoContrato        =   TC.IDtipocontrato "_
        & " INNER JOIN  LI_Mercado              M    WITH (NOLOCK) ON TCD.Mercado               =   M.Mercado and TCD.Empresa = M.EmpresaBD"_
        & " LEFT JOIN   LI_Moedas                    MDS    WITH (NOLOCK) ON TCD.Moeda          =   MDS.Moeda "_
        & " WHERE       TC.IdTipoContrato = " & Request("IdTipoContrato") & " " _
        & " ORDER BY    TCD.Id " _
        & "      ,      TC.IdTipoContrato "

       rs.Open safeSQL(SQL), con, 1, 1
       NLinhas = rs.RecordCount
       'numLinhaAtual = 1
       While not rs.EOF 

   %>
```

Quando abro a página ( juntamente com o resto do código que não está apresentado) obtenho o seguinte erro:

> Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server error '80040e14'
>
> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ORDER'.
>
> /GIP-eP/administrativo/contratos/gestaoTipoContratos.asp, line 915

O que estou a fazer de mal??

Agradeço desde já pela ajuda!

Fiz um Response.Write SQL e obtive isto

```
SELECT Id = TCD.Id ,    IdTipoContrato  =   TC.IdTipoContrato , Codigo  =   TCD.Codigo ,    Mercado =   M.Mercado , Empresa =   M.EmpresaBD , Valor =   TCD.Valor , Descricao   =   TCD.Descricao , Moeda = MDS.Moeda , Ativo = TCD.Ativo FROM  LI_TipoContratosDetalhe TCD WITH (NOLOCK) INNER JOIN    LI_TipoContratos TC WITH (NOLOCK) ON TCD.IdTipoContrato =   TC.IDtipocontrato INNER JOIN    LI_Mercado  M WITH (NOLOCK) ON TCD.Mercado  =   M.Mercado and TCD.Empresa = M.EmpresaBD LEFT JOIN   LI_Moedas MDS   WITH (NOLOCK) ON TCD.Moeda  =   MDS.Moeda WHERE TC.IdTipoContrato = ORDER BY TCD.Id ,   TC.IdTipoContrato
```

Não sei estão-se a referir a isto, ainda sou um pouco novato nisto

Já corrigi o código agora o IdTipoContrato já é introduzido corretamente:

```
SELECT Id = TCD.Id ,    Codigo  =   TCD.Codigo ,    Mercado =   M.Mercado , Empresa =   M.EmpresaBD ,   Valor   =   TCD.Valor , Descricao   =   TCD.Descricao , Moeda = MDS.Moeda , Ativo = TCD.Ativo FROM  LI_TipoContratosDetalhe TCD WITH (NOLOCK) INNER JOIN    LI_TipoContratos TC WITH (NOLOCK) ON TCD.IdTipoContrato =   TC.IDtipocontrato INNER JOIN    LI_Mercados M WITH (NOLOCK) ON TCD.Mercado  =   M.Mercado and TCD.Empresa = M.EmpresaBD LEFT JOIN   LI_Moedas MDS WITH (NOLOCK) ON TCD.Moeda    =   MDS.Moeda WHERE TC.IdTipoContrato = 3 ORDER BY TCD.Codigo
```

Obrigado

Comment: Consegues imprimir o SQL gerado antes de executar?

Comment: Provavelmente o que está ocorrendo é que `Request("IdTipoContrato")` não esteja retornando nenhum valor e com isso gerando seu SQL de forma errada.

Comment: Leia isso: [Injeção de SQL](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inje%C3%A7%C3%A3o_de_SQL).

Comment: @IdkWhy vc poderia postar o SQL gerado pelas concatenações ou o valor que está retornando em `Request("IdTipoContrato")`?

Comment: Tenta imprimir o resultado do  safeSQL(SQL) e posta aqui pra analisarmos.

Comment: A sua variável `IdTipoContrato` está vazia

Comment: Seu Request("IdTipoContrato") está vazio. Sugiro você utilizar parametros ao invés de concatenar a string, pois acaba abrindo uma ótima oportunidade para SQL injection.

Comment: Acontece que o código acima ficou fora do If que eu tinha inserido, já o introduzi dentro do if agora o IdTipoContrato recebe o Id certo, Obrigado, por me mostrarem onde estava o problema.

Comment: Coloque o `Request("IdTipoContrato")`entre aspas simples.

Comment: Assim: `& " WHERE       TC.IdTipoContrato = '" & Request("IdTipoContrato") & "' " _`